# Change the selector of a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help. See if you can help me out. 
I have a function whose form is:

```
$this.find(settings.selector).each(function(index) {
```

Anyway, depending on a variable can change the selector as follows:

```
$this.each(function(index) {
```

Can you give me some idea how to do it? I hope I have explained roughly.
Thank you.

Comment: `$t = settings.use_selector ? $this.find(settings.selector) : $this; $t.each(...` Like that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a temp variable like

```
var $els;
if (some_condition) {
    $els = $this.find(settings.selector)
} else {
    $els = $this;
}
$els.each(function (index) {});
```